# Can a User Case be accessed through a module by another user?

Tags: commcare

Can a module list user cases in its case list, and can those cases then be updated by that module?

Or are user cases specifically restricted to access by that user?

The use case I am thinking of, would be to allow a supervisor to update case properties on a subordinate's user case.  For instance, to record a training or certification for that subordinate.

Answer (score 1):

The user case is directly assigned to the mobile worker and it isn't recommended to reassign that case to anyone else.

If you need functionality like this, there are a few options:
- Use a different case type that is assigned to the location (so that supervisors and supervisees can both use and update it).
- Create a delegate case from the user-case that is assigned to the location.  This will then make the user case appear for anyone who is assigned to that location (or can view that location's cases).

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to list user cases in the case list. A single user case is loaded for the mobile user using the mobile application.

However you may be able to accomplish something similar with [Organizations](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Organizations). With organizations you could setup a structure that would allow a supervisor to see all of its supervisee's cases.